# How to make chromium headless wait till the reactjs is loaded with the data from the fetch call

Tags: django, reactjs, pdf

I have a Django project and recently I am trying to convert the front end to react one view at a time. I am using Django-hardcopy(https://github.com/loftylabs/django-hardcopy) to create a pdf report for me which was working for Django templates.

But now that I am using react, the chrome headless does not wait till the fetch call is completed and just prints out the empty page in the pdf as react first renders the DOM element (so the data is still not fetched).

I did go through some StackOverflow answers like using

```
--virtual-time-budget=10000
```

But did not work.
I tried to delay the reportview with

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

I really cannot use react to render pdf at this moment because of some other restrictions.

Is there any way to do this?

If you guys need any more info let me know.

Just an overview of the code I have:
views.py

```
class ReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, PDFViewMixin):
   def get_context_data(self, pk, **kwargs):
             ....
```

mytemplate.html

```
<div class="react-baseline-div">
<div id="baseline-energy-root"></div>
</div>

{% compress js %}
<script src="{% static 'react/build_files/_reactify.js' %}"></script>
<script src="/static/react/build_files/baseline_energy.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/static/react/build_files/main.baseline_energy.chunk.js"></script>
{% endcompress %}
```

This has the react build files and the `<div>` that connects to react app(react app renders perfectly) Just not in the pdf.